# How to display all subcategory's posts instead of ".first" | Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a blog with subcategories/main categories and on the main category, I want it to list the posts from all of its child categories. I got it working with using the method `.first` but I just don't know how to handle this in the way I need it to.

**BlogCategory Model:**

```
class BlogCategory < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  has_many :posts

  # This is called a self referential relation. This is where records in a table may point to other records in the same table.
  has_many :sub_categories, class_name: "BlogCategory", foreign_key: :parent_id
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'BlogCategory', foreign_key: :parent_id
  # This is a scope to load the top level categories and eager-load their posts, subcategories, and the subcategories' posts too.
  scope :top_level, -> { where(parent_id: nil).includes :posts, sub_categories: :posts }

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.nil? || name_changed?
  end

end
```

**blog_categories Controller:**

```
def show
  @cat              = BlogCategory.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @category         = @cat.parent
  @posts            = @cat.posts
  @sub_category     = @cat.sub_categories.first
  unless @sub_category.nil?
    @relatives      = @sub_category.posts
  end
end

private

  def cat_params
    params.require(:blog_category).permit(:name, :parent_id, :sub_category)
  end

  def main_cat
    @cat = BlogCategory.parent_id.nil?
  end
```

**Post Model:** `belongs_to :blog_category`

I have tried a few configurations of `.all` `.each` and seen if `.collection` worked, but these didn't seem to fix my problem.

Thank you I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a has many association in your Category model like this

```
has_many :sub_category_posts, through: :sub_categories, source: :posts
```

In your controller

```
@relatives = @cat.sub_category_posts
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I didn't recognize this as a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want all the posts. If a post belongs to a category, that category will be a child of another category, and eventually, you'll have the main category, so, you could do something like:

`@posts = Post.where.not(blog_category: nil)`

If you have many main categories, one per blog, you need to implement a recursive method.

You could also use `https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set` and do something like:

```
@cat.descendants # array of all children, children's children, etc., excluding self
```

https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/wiki/Awesome-nested-set-cheat-sheet

Comment: I have 5 main categories and most have 2 or more subcategories based on the `parent_id` pointed at the main category's `.id`.